# React Amchart - How to remove animation when loading charts

Tags: reactjs, amcharts

I am using amcharts in the React Hooks environment.

I'm using force-directed-tree.
https://www.amcharts.com/demos/force-directed-tree/

The data applied to the chart is filtered based on high values and then reapplying.
Every time the data is reapply, the chart is rendered and the animation continues to be applied.

How to remove animation when loading charts

Or we would appreciate it if you could tell us how to apply the scrollbar provided by amcharts to this chart.

```
    useEffect(() => {
        const chart = am4core.create('networkChart', am4plugins_forceDirected.ForceDirectedTree);
        const networkSeries = chart.series.push(new am4plugins_forceDirected.ForceDirectedSeries());
        chart.data = data;
        chart.dataSource.updateCurrentData = true;
        chart.animationPlayed = true;
        chart.dataSource.reloadFrequency = 1000;

        networkSeries.dataFields.id = 'name';
        networkSeries.dataFields.value = 'value';
        networkSeries.dataFields.name = 'name';
        networkSeries.dataFields.children = 'children';
        networkSeries.nodes.template.tooltipText = '{name}:{value}';
        networkSeries.nodes.template.fillOpacity = 1;
        networkSeries.manyBodyStrength = -20;
        networkSeries.links.template.strength = 0.8;
        networkSeries.links.template.distance = 1;
        networkSeries.minRadius = am4core.percent(3);
        networkSeries.maxRadius = am4core.percent(10);
        networkSeries.nodes.template.label.text = '{name}';
        networkSeries.fontSize = 12;
        networkSeries.maxLevels = 4;

        networkSeries.events.disableType('inited', function() {
            networkSeries.animate(
                {
                    property: 'velocityDecay',
                    to: 1,
                },
                3000,
            );
        });

        // Add Legend
        chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
        chart.legend.labels.template.fill = am4core.color('#fff');

    }, [data]);
```

Comment: Can't remove initial animation. It's part of the collision-detection process where nodes figure out positions where they do not overlap each other according to rules.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't want the these to be used, so I used the `unuseTheme` and passed the animation theme to it. This removed the animations with respect to the chart.

Example:

`am4core.unuseTheme(am4themesAnimated);`

Answer (score 0):

To Add scrollbar

```
let chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

...

let scrollbarX = new am4charts.XYChartScrollbar();
scrollbarX.series.push(networkSeries);
chart.scrollbarX = scrollbarX;
```

https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/tutorials/customizing-chart-scrollbar/